# Force to open image (anchor tag) in new tab instead of downloading it

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

How to force to open image from anchor in new tab?

```
<a href="https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/..." target="_blank">
    Click to see in new tab
</a>
```

When I click on this link, **image starts to downloading instead.**

I know that there is attribute `download` for anchor tag, but I need opposite one.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question :P

Comment: Depends on the response headers set. You should host image yourself so you can control the headers. Non-downloading should be the default behavior.

Comment: @MladenIlić For sure, but I need to depend on `lookaside.facebook` domain

Comment: I'm somewhat confident that this isn't something you can force from JS/HTML alone. It depends on the response headers, as said, and also on browser settings (of what to do with each file extension).